# Inference Regarding Definite Integral of Product of Two Functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Please let me know if the below inference would be correct. Please provide full details and clarify any additional assumptions made. If the question is too trivial or not well formed, please let me know.

Does this hold for: $\forall Q\,\geq0$ and if $ \forall x\text{ ,  } f\left(x\right)\leq0$?

$$
\int_{0}^{Q}g\left(x\right)\,f\left(x\right)\,dx<\int_{0}^{Q}h\left(x\right)\,f\left(x\right)\,dx
$$
$$
\Rightarrow\int_{0}^{Q}g\left(x\right)\,dx>\int_{0}^{Q}h\left(x\right)\,dx\quad\text{ If }\forall x\text{ ,  } f\left(x\right)\leq0
$$

Related Question:

[Is this expression positive, negative or both under different regions of positive real numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2325847/is-this-expression-positive-negative-or-both-under-different-regions-of-positiv)

Comment: Counterexample: if $f=0$, then choosing $h-g=x$ gives a contradiction.  I believe additional conditions on $f$ are needed, such as $f>0$.

Comment: @user254433, thanks for this suggestion. How about if I change the $\leq$ to $<$ not for $f$ but for the implication and the given statement?

Comment: Let $f(x)=-1$ for $x\in[0,1]$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x\in(1,Q]$, assuming $Q>1$, of course.  If we put $h-g=-1$ on $[0,1]$ and $h-g=3/(Q-1)$ on $(1,Q]$, then the first inequality is true, but not the second.  I used discontinuous functions for simplicity, but the same idea works even for continuous functions if $f(x)=0$ on a nonzero interval.

Comment: @user254433, thanks for this. Would it suffice to have $g,f>0$? I believe, that does not suffice as well. Could you please put down your thoughts on what conditions on $g,h$ need to hold for the above inference? In your earlier comment you say $f>0$, but that clashes with $f\leq0$? Did you mean something different?

Comment: I meant $f<0$, but in fact, unless $f$ is a negative constant, the implication will not be true for arbitrary $h-g$.  Try imposing that $f$ and $h-g$ be monotone functions (e.g. $f$ nonincreasing, with $f(0)\le 0$).

Comment: @user254433 Thanks for your very helpful and patient clarifications. With $h=K>0$, a constant and $g=(Q-x)$ a decreasing function, I believe the two conditions hold when $f\leq0$. Please see related question where this is utilised.